# Seekbar and setText displays old output

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm testing the seek bar component to get the feel for it so I add it to my app. The goal is simple when you drag the cursor it changes the text to indicate the progress. But for some reason when dragging it across the screen it leaves left over images of the cursor as well the previous results instead of just replace the text with the new one. Here's the code. Very basic I would think.

```
public class Progressbar extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

{

```
SeekBar bar; // declare seekbar object variable
// declare text label objects
TextView textAction;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // load the layout
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_progressbar);     
     bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); // make seekbar object
     bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // set seekbar listener.
     // since we are using this class as the listener the class is "this"


     // make text label for action
     textAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewAction);

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // change action text label to changing
    textAction.setText(textAction.getText() + "\n" +"SeekBar progress is at: "+ progress);

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textAction.setText("starting to track touch");

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress()); // set the shade of the previous value.
    textAction.setText("ended tracking touch");     
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are Appending the previous text with the new progress. Why wont you do this to check the Seekbar.

```
textAction.setText(""+ progress);
```

Comment: I've done that as well however the set text appear right on top of each other instead of just displaying the new one. So it just winds up looking jarbled.